# Why does List IndexOf allow out-of-range start index?

Tags: c#, .net, list, indexoutofrangeexception

Why does [`List<T>.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8t42k5w(v=vs.110).aspx) allow out-of-range start index?

```
var list = new List<int>() { 100 };
Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(1/*item*/, 1/*start index*/));
```

There will not be any exceptions. But there is no item with `1` index in this collection! There is just one item with `0` index.
So, why does `.Net` allow you to do it?

Comment: What exactly is output to the console form this code?

Comment: There is legal output: -1
It means there is no such element in specified range

Comment: If you try index 2 it would throw an exception.

Comment: Looks like special case for List.Length, MSDN states that 0 can be used with empty list

Comment: I know that I will get exception If I try to use index 2.
But why can I use index 1? There is no such index. There is no such element.

Comment: Because it doesn't do any compile-time checks about whether or not that might be a valid index and there is no reason to expect it would.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel he's asking why its not throwing a *run-time exception*

Comment: Your call is the same as `list.IndexOf(1/*item*/, 1/*start index*/, 0 /* count*/)`. So, index 0 with count of 1 and index 1 with a count of 0 both make sense. If you are consuming items in a list, the final search returns -1 and you don't have to keep checking remaining length as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I understand why.
It's kind of easier whay of realisation of methods like this.
Look:

```
public int IndexOf(T item, int index)
{
    if (index > this._size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
    }
    return Array.IndexOf<T>(this._items, item, index, this._size - index);
}
```

This method overload use another, more common, overload:

```
return Array.IndexOf<T>(this._items, item, index, this._size - index);
```

So this method also use it:

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
```

So it doens't make sence if this code:

```
var list = new List<int>(); /*empty!*/
Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(1/*item*/));
```

will throw an `Exception` . But there is no way to use this overload of `IndexOf` using common overload without this admission.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, if someone should take care of an invalid input it's the runtime and not the compiler since the input is of the same valid type (`int`).

With that said, actually, seeing the source code of [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8zse0c(v=vs.110).aspx) making it seem like an implementation bug:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public int IndexOf(T item, int index)
{
    if (index > this._size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
    }
    return Array.IndexOf<T>(this._items, item, index, this._size - index);
}
```

As you can see, it was intended to not allow you to insert an invalid index which is bigger than the size of the list, but the comparison is done with `>` instead of `>=`.

- The following code returns `0`:

  ```
  var list = new List<int>() { 100 };
  Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(100/*item*/, 0/*start index*/));
  ```
- The following code returns `-1`:

  ```
  var list = new List<int>() { 100 };
  Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(100/*item*/, 1/*start index*/));
  ```
- While ***The following code throws an `Exception`***:

  ```
  var list = new List<int>() { 100 };
  Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(100/*item*/, 2/*start index*/));
  ```

***There is no reason what so ever for the second and third cases to behave differently*** which makes it seem as a bug in the implementation of [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8zse0c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, [the documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8zse0c(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException | index is outside the range of valid indexes for the `List<T>`.

Which as we have just seen ***is not what happening***.

Note: the same behaviour happens with arrays:

```
int[] arr =  { 100 };

//Output: 0
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(arr, 100/*item*/, 0/*start index*/));

//Output: -1
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(arr, 100/*item*/, 1/*start index*/));

//Throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(arr, 100/*item*/, 2/*start index*/));
```

Comment: ...or it's just a design decision and not a bug as you are very quick to conclude. If the docs specifically state that 0 (== `.Count`) is valid for an empty list, it only makes sense to allow the same value as `.Count` for all lists.

Comment: Give me a reasonable reason to allow `size` and throw on `size + 1` when indexes are zero based.

Comment: It's an option, still the same result could be achieved by adding a validation to the `for` loop, still it is very minor reason to allow such an odd behavior...

Comment: This is not odd behavior. You have array with 3 elements. If you start on index 0 you have skip 0 elements and there are 3 to go. If you start at 3 you have skip 3 elements and there are 0 to go. Why would you prohibit starting at the end of collection?

Comment: Intuitively if you approach an index which is out of the `Array`/`List` It should throw an `Exception`. If It doesn't - There should not be a difference between index which is too large by 1 or by 30.

Comment: I think you are thinking about this method like IndexOf(item, startAtIndex) but its really IndexOf(item, startBeforeIndex).

Comment: It's called `startIndex`. That's just my interpretation you don't have to agree...

Answer (score 9):

It allows it because someone decided this was OK, and that someone either wrote the spec or implemented the method.

It is also somewhat documented in [`List(T).IndexOf` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8t42k5w(v=vs.110).aspx):

> 0 (zero) is valid in an empty list.

*(which I also take that `Count` is a valid start index for any list)*

Note that the same thing is documented, but slightly better documented, for [`Array.IndexOf` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2fz03t(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If `startIndex` equals `Array.Length`, the method returns -1. If `startIndex` is greater than `Array.Length`, the method throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Let me clarify my answer here.

You're asking "Why does this method allow this input".

The only legal reason is "Because someone implemented the method so that it did".

Is it a bug? It may very well be. The documentation only says that 0 is legal start index for an empty list, it does not directly say that 1 is legal or not for a list with a single element in it. The exception documentation for the method seems to contradict this (as has been brought up in comments) which seems to be in favor of it being a bug.

But the only reason for "why does it do this" is that someone actually implemented the method that way. It may be a conscious choice, it may be a bug, it may be an oversight either in the code or in the documentation.

The only one that can tell which one it is would be the person or people that implemented this method.

Comment: The behaviour for a general `List<T>` size actually contradicts the documentation (look at my answer).

Comment: The documentation does not say what happens if start index is equal to the length of a non-empty list, so I would tend to disagree.

Comment: It clearly says it: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException | index is outside the range of valid indexes for the List<T>`

Comment: Yet it also says that 0 is legal for an empty list, which is not a legal index for an empty list. I'm not saying any of this makes sense.

Comment: It looks like no realisation error. So someone maded this decision, but does anyone know why?

Comment: Right, so the 64K question is what part of the library checks for (and is coupled to) that -1 return value... :P

Answer (score 6):

Of course the only one who can say for sure why is this are the people that made that decision.

The only logical reason I see (and that's my guess) is to allow usage like this

```
for (int index = list.IndexOf(value); index >= 0; index = list.IndexOf(value, index + 1))
{
    // do something
}
```

or in other words, to be able to restart safely the search from the next index of the last **successful** search.

This might not look a very common scenario, but is typical pattern when processing strings (for instance when one want to avoid `Split`). Which reminds me that [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) has the same behavior and is a bit better documented (although without specifying the reason):

> The startIndex parameter can range from 0 to the **length** of the string instance. If startIndex equals the length of the string instance, the method returns -1.

To resume, since `Array`, `string` and `List<T>` share the same behavior, apparently it's intended and definitely not an implementation bug.

Answer (score 3):

To understand what's happening we can take a look at the [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,3be9c75bca72d89a,references):

```
public int IndexOf(T item, int index) {
    if (index > _size)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= -1);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() < Count);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    return Array.IndexOf(_items, item, index, _size - index);
}
```

`_size` here is equivalent to `list.Count` so when you have one item you can use an `index` of `1` even if it doesn't exist in the list.

Unless there is a special reason that I'm not seeing, this looks like a good old off-by-one error in the framework. The documentation even mentions that an exceptions should be thrown if

> `index` is outside the range of valid indexes for the `List<T>`.